# Image field is blank in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Respected Sir/Madam,

i am using sqlserver database with

Table Name `User` and fields

```
UserName nvarchar(30),
Photo image
```

i have added a data table with column name `photo` set to `DataType System.Byte[]`

now in crystal report i have dragged Photo field from DataTable lists.
however Photo is not being displayed in my crystal report following below is my .cs code:

```
SqlConnection myConn1 = new SqlConnection();
myConn1.ConnectionString = "Data Source=B-1F60BB54;Initial Catalog=User_Tracking1;User ID=sa;Password=sa123";

try
{            
    myConn1.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select UserName,Photo", myConn1);

    DataSet ds1 = null;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;

    ds1 = new DataSet();
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);

    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    string rptpath = Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt");
    rpt.Load(rptpath);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    adapter.Fill(dt);
    adapter.Fill(ds1, "DataTable1");
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds1);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;      
}
```

so please help me regd this i dont know how to

Comment: your select query is not perfect "select UserName,Photo" it must be select UserName,Photo from User

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi If you believe that's the solution to the problem then you should post it as an answer rather than attempting to edit the question to fix the code.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : please add your image save code here too. because nothing wrong in this code accept this line.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi I don't have any code - I don't even program in C#. Your edit to this question simply came up in my list to review, and since it was an incorrect edit I felt the need to explicitly tell you not to do it in the future. I'll re-iterate: If you believe that the fix to the SQL statement answers this question, **post it as an answer**, do not edit the question.

Comment: Check this Answer it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993639/error-while-add-image-dynamically-from-local-path-in-crystal-report/23994639#23994639