# Error While Add Image Dynamically from Local Path In Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my Crystal Report I need To add Header Image from specific Folder Path, for that I done Below Code

```
private void AddImage_ProdfailReport()
    {
        try
        {
            // here i have define a simple datatable inwhich image will recide 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // object of data row 
            DataRow drow;
            // add the column in table to store the image of Byte array type 
            dt.Columns.Add("Image", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
            drow = dt.NewRow();
            // define the filestream object to read the image 
            FileStream fs;
            // define te binary reader to read the bytes of image 
            BinaryReader br;
            // check the existance of image 
            if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Footer.Jpg"))
            {
                // open image in file stream 
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Footer.Jpg", FileMode.Open);
            }
            else
            {
                // if phot does not exist show the nophoto.jpg file 
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Footer.jpg", FileMode.Open);
            }
            // initialise the binary reader from file streamobject 
            br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // define the byte array of filelength 
            byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
            // read the bytes from the binary reader 
            imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));
            drow[0] = imgbyte;
            // add the image in bytearray 
            dt.Rows.Add(drow);
            // add row into the datatable 
            br.Close();
            // close the binary reader 
            fs.Close();
            // close the file stream 
            CreRe_ProdFail rptobj = new CreRe_ProdFail();
            // object of crystal report 
            rptobj.SetDataSource(dt);
            // set the datasource of crystalreport object 
            crv1.ReportSource = rptobj;
            //set the report source 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error handling 
           MessageBox.Show("Missing Footer.jpg in application folder");
        }
        // run the application to view image in report 
    }
```

I created a field in a datatable of the dataset and
change the DataType to System.Byte()

Then I drag this field to the report 
But its Showing An  Error "This Field name is not known" , while Opening Report..
I am not getting what is Problem
Please help me in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done It;
I am trying to add Data from Database And Image From Local Path and show in Crystal report; I done it by below code:

First:  I created a New Column ("Image") in a datatable of the dataset and change the DataType to System.Byte()

Second : Drag And drop this image Filed Where I want.

```
private void LoadReport()
    {
        frmCheckWeigher rpt = new frmCheckWeigher();
        CryRe_DailyBatch report = new CryRe_DailyBatch();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable_DailyBatch1TableAdapter ta = new CheckWeigherReportViewer.DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable_DailyBatch1TableAdapter();
        DataSet1.DataTable_DailyBatch1DataTable table = ta.GetData(clsLogs.strStartDate_rpt, clsLogs.strBatchno_Rpt, clsLogs.cmdeviceid); // Data from Database
        DataTable dt = GetImageRow(table, "Footer.Jpg");

        report.SetDataSource(dt);
        crv1.ReportSource = report;
        crv1.Refresh();

    }
```

// By this Function I merge My Image data into dataTable

```
 private DataTable GetImageRow(DataTable dt, string ImageName)
    {

        try
        {

            FileStream fs;
            BinaryReader br;

            if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName))
            {
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName, FileMode.Open);
            }
            else
            {
                // if photo does not exist show the nophoto.jpg file 
                fs = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + ImageName, FileMode.Open);
            }
            // initialise the binary reader from file streamobject 
            br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // define the byte array of filelength 
            byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
            // read the bytes from the binary reader 
            imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)));

            dt.Rows[0]["Image"] = imgbyte;


            br.Close();
            // close the binary reader 
            fs.Close();
            // close the file stream 




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error handling 
            MessageBox.Show("Missing " + ImageName + "or nophoto.jpg in application folder");
        }
        return dt;
        // Return Datatable After Image Row Insertion

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

First, add a graphic as a placeholder into your report where you want it to display.

Then, right-click the graphic -> 'Format Graphic' -> 'Picture' tab -> Add a formula

under 'Graphic Location' that builds your path string.

Something like 'C:\My Folder\' + {table.Clgid} + '.jpg' should work.

If your Higher version then,

Report Header RightClick => INSERT => OLE Object => CREATE NEW as Drawing

After Right Click ON object => select Picture tab => set Location formula under Graphic Location

Comment: thank You Hiral for your response, bt I m nt getting you, I want to give flexibility to user to add header image whatever they want their company logo etc, by just replacing image on specific path.. I know How to Do it by RDLC report but for crystal i dont know Much, If you know some link, where i can learn or which explain step by step solution etc, kindly fwd it. Noted: I am using Visual Studio 2008, and i didnt find Graphics as a placeholder anywhere.